# New ranked banked days LOL season 2021

Tags: league-of-legends

I know that the new ranked system starting from diamond allows you to bank days so you do not get demoted or have your lp decayed in case of inactivity. FYI under my understanding if you are inactive in ranked from d4 and above, the system does not decay your lp for the first 28 days of inactivity. However if you do play ranked, for each game of ranked played you gain 7 days of activity days which are banked.

If that understanding of mine is correct then if I play 4 games of ranked then I technically gain **28+7*4=56** inactivity days? So I will not be punished if I do not get active within those 56 days?

Additionally if I play 10 ranked games within the 28 days, then I get **28+7*10=98** days of inactivity?

I am not sure exactly how this works. I am asking this because I have work and because of time I might not be able to play ranked at all in certain weeks or months. I grinned hard to get to d4 I do not want to get demoted to plat 1 either incase I stop playing ranked for a while.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not think you can have more than 56 days.

> Diamond
>
> - Each game played banks 7 days of activity, **up to 28**
> - After 28 days of inactivity, you'll begin consuming banked days (this initial grace period is skipped if you decayed into Diamond from Master+)
> - Once all banked days have been consumed, you lose 50 LP each day until you fall out of Diamond

([Ranked 2021 Rundown](https://na.leagueoflegends.com/en-us/news/game-updates/ranked-2021-rundown/), emphasis mine)

So you can have 28 banked days, and a grace period of 28 days. This puts you at 28+28 = 56 days of inactivity before decay.

Comment: thank you for your clarification, after 56 days, can you have the same 56 day cycle by playing only 4 ranked games after the initial 56 days has passed?

Comment: @AuroraBorealis I'm not familiar enough with LOL to answer that.